# Predicting a GAM in R with an offset

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict, gam, mgcv

I am trying to predict the output of two GAMs using the package mgcv and the `predict()` function and for some reason one output has the smooth prediction I am looking for and the other does not.

My data set looks like this:

```
   structure(list(count = c(27354, 89269, 11399, 51520, 13693, 82683, 
15043, 54014, 40463, 42597, 47765, 56461, 54339, 28096, 27382, 
53604, 65726, 120070, 58144, 91556, 94739, 85911, 57353, 143233
), count2 = c(9104, 27683, 6161, 13165, 6255, 32040, 8397, 29511, 
23915, 15414, 31257, 27400, 35852, 10114, 16531, 26471, 37832, 
37633, 32895, 41865, 46381, 36281, 31112, 52742), offset = c(18814.72941, 
19435.38123, 19994.7137, 19825.32873, 17993.1975, 17420.34353, 
18014.97538, 19847.19262, 18830.19344, 19150.53897, 19117.28981, 
19261.53191, 17776.715, 18015.96455, 16574.83571, 17823.48409, 
19209.3204, 19421.52235, 19826.43979, 19783.67929, 19090, 18553, 
18758, 19073), Season = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L), .Label = c("fall", "spring", "summer", "winter"), class = "factor"), 
    timestep = c(2004.83333333333, 2004.58333333333, 2005.08333333333, 
    2005.33333333333, 2006.83333333333, 2006.58333333333, 2007.08333333333, 
    2007.33333333333, 2008.83333333333, 2008.58333333333, 2009.08333333333, 
    2009.33333333333, 2012.83333333333, 2012.58333333333, 2013.08333333333, 
    2013.33333333333, 2016.83333333333, 2016.58333333333, 2017.08333333333, 
    2017.33333333333, 2021.58333333333, 2021.83333333333, 2022.08333333333, 
    2022.33333333333)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

My gams look like this:

```
library(mgcv)
gam1<-gam(count~s(timestep)+offset(log(offset))+
                s(Season, bs="re"),family=nb,method="REML",data=check)

gam2<-gam(count2~s(timestep)+offset(log(offset))+
                s(Season, bs="re"),family=nb,method="REML",data=check)
```

My newdata and prediction data frames look like this (offset equal to 1 in new data so that predictions equal counts per unit offset):

```
structure(list(count = c(27354, 89269, 11399, 51520, 13693, 82683, 
15043, 54014, 40463, 42597, 47765, 56461, 54339, 28096, 27382, 
53604, 65726, 120070, 58144, 91556, 94739, 85911, 57353, 143233
), count2 = c(9104, 27683, 6161, 13165, 6255, 32040, 8397, 29511, 
23915, 15414, 31257, 27400, 35852, 10114, 16531, 26471, 37832, 
37633, 32895, 41865, 46381, 36281, 31112, 52742), offset = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), Season = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("fall", 
"spring", "summer", "winter"), class = "factor"), timestep = c(2004.83333333333, 
2004.58333333333, 2005.08333333333, 2005.33333333333, 2006.83333333333, 
2006.58333333333, 2007.08333333333, 2007.33333333333, 2008.83333333333, 
2008.58333333333, 2009.08333333333, 2009.33333333333, 2012.83333333333, 
2012.58333333333, 2013.08333333333, 2013.33333333333, 2016.83333333333, 
2016.58333333333, 2017.08333333333, 2017.33333333333, 2021.58333333333, 
2021.83333333333, 2022.08333333333, 2022.33333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")

df<- cbind(check,
                    predict(gam1, 
                    se.fit=TRUE,
                    type="response",newdata = newdata))

df2<- cbind(check,
                predict(gam2, 
                se.fit=TRUE,
                type="response",newdata = newdata))
```

When I plot these predictions, df2 comes out as a smooth but df comes out very jagged. See plots/code below:

```
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=timestep, y=count))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=(fit - 2*se.fit), ymax=(fit + 2*se.fit), x=timestep),
              data=df, 
              alpha=0.3, 
              inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_line( aes(y=(fit)), data=df) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18)+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=11.5),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12))+
  theme(strip.background =element_rect(fill="white"))+ theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"),axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2004, 2022, by = 2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))


ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=timestep, y=count))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=(fit - 2*se.fit), ymax=(fit + 2*se.fit), x=timestep),
              data=df2, 
              alpha=0.3, 
              inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_line( aes(y=(fit)), data=df2) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18)+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=11.5),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12))+
  theme(strip.background =element_rect(fill="white"))+ theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"),axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2004, 2022, by = 2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

df:
[image]
df2:
[image]

Can someone help me set up my predictions so that they both come out as smooth estimates? And I am also wondering why it worked for df2 but not df. The structure of the timesteps is exactly the same for both gams so if anyone can take a look and help me get the correct predictions for these GAMs, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I guess you use your original data to create your `newdata` object? Your predict method is  not provided. Instead of using the same original data point, create equal intervals in timestep from 2004 to 2022 to predict. Use the game estimates and se to plot. You can append back in your raw data as points to check against the model.

Comment: I think the problem is that season is not a good predictor of `count2` so the prediction is smooth over time. The variable `season` is a significant predictor for `count`, so you're seeing the effect of seasonality in the predictions.  If `newdata` had `season` that was constant, you would see a smooth line.

Comment: You are exactly right! When I set the season to a constant, I get a smooth.